# Django static file is not loading in my computer (windows 10) but its working on others computer (windows 10)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've run my project in various computer (windows 10), python 3.7.2, django 2.1.7
In every computer its working properly except mine.
Only in my computer bootstrap files is not loading from static directory. when I use CDN link its loads .css and working as my expectation. 
I've unstall python and django, cleaned python directory from appData and reinstalled python and django. but its still not working. What should I do?

N.B: I've tested my project in various computers of similar configuration.
Here is given config code from setting.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'testApp'
```

]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
  '/static/',
)

Comment: can you show ur settings.py

Comment: I've edited my question and given code from setting.py

Comment: Is `DEBUG` set to true or false?

Comment: Did you do a collectstatic?